# Ansible: Conditional check to either output name of child group or individual host based on specified limit

Tags: ansible

Hi to all friendly automagicians,

I'm using ansible in order to administrate tasks on a heap of embedded linux nodes that are rapidly expanding. Since our project is using hipchat, I figured it's necessary to start notifying to a room so I don't keep annoying researchers by rebooting or something when working on a node.

I have divided the hosts inventory up into child groups based on their switch ports and vlans. 
So when I want to do something to all production, I don't use use the limit option.. 
When I want to do something to a specific chain of nodes, I limit to a child group.. and when I want to do something individually I limit to the hostname.

So I am using a notify at the end of a task to post to hipchat like so:

```
- name: "Notify hipchat" 
    hipchat_v2:
      msg='{{ inventory_hostname }} was updated from {{ version.stdout }} to {{ newversion.stdout }}'
```

The problem is when I go to do an action like system wide updates in batches of child groups it's going result in a message for each node to the room which will mean hundreds over a couple of hours, so in this case I'd rather output the name of the child group.

However I still want to maintain the ability to notify room of the same action performed on an individual host.

That's where my question comes in:

Is there a way I can configure the playbook to use a conditional test in order to output an individual host name if the action is limited to a single host name like I'm doing with {{ inventory hostname }}, yet only output the name of the child group if the action is limited to a child group instead?

So in a logical flow (**yes I know this isn't real code - just code logic**), something like:

```
If --limit option = group
then print group
elif --limit option = group:research-nodes
then print research-nodes
elif --limit option = individual host
then print hostname
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it - I do something similar with some playbooks I have.  The trick is to have well defined group names, and to pass a host, group, etc. into your script as a variable.  So your playbook might look a little like this:

```
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
- tasks: 
    - name: reboot node
      command: shutdown -r now

    - name: Group notify
      local_action: hipchat_v2 msg="Group {{ host }} was rebooted"
      run_once: true
      when: host.find("group_") != -1

    - name: Individual notify
      local_action: hipchat_v2 msg="Host {{ inventory_hostname }} was rebooted"
      when: host.find("group_") == -1
```

This example would assume that any group names start with the prefix "group_" The first task would invoke the hipchat task once on the host Ansible is running from if the `host` variable contains "group_". The second task would invoke that hipchat task if "group_" isn't found in the host variable.  So you would invoke ansible with something like this:

```
$ ansible-playbook reboot.yml --extra-vars="host=group_production"
```